# How to download latest TestNG jar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I need to download the latest TestNG jar (testng6.9.4). From where I can download this?

I am looking for jar than eclipse plug-in. So please help me.

Answer (score 7):

You can download the TestNG jar file from the below link :

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng

If you are using maven and want to add it to your dependency use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps you...
You can get the maven dependency code from the following site:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.11

Comment: The latest version of TestNG is 6.11